LDAP Users at AWS Client VPN via Keycloak SAML
Friends,
I have OpenLDAP configured with Keycloak realm. Now I want to integrate Keycloak SAML to AWS IAM Identify provider and then utilise same within AWS Client VPN connection.
I am not getting proper documentation for this. Can you please help.
I want to facilitate my OpenLDAP users to connect AWS Client VPN and then access AWS Resources.
OpenLDAP configured within Keycloak.
Keycloak SAML exported from Realm setting page and then configured same within AWS IAM Identity Provider.
Created AWS Client VPN Connection using above created Identify provider and Associated a subnet.
Downloaded client vpn config and tried within AWS Client VPN application. Keycloak page opens but fails
In other words, I have tried this
OpenLDAP -> Keycloak -> AWS IAM Identify Provider as SAML -> AWS Client VPN Connection -> Download Config -> Tried accessing but keycloak page says
We are sorry...
Invalid Request
at keycloak log I see this error
type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=demo, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.19.100.121, error=client_not_found, reason=Cannot_match_source_hash
